# 2 different NSManagedObjectContexts save causes infinite memory allocation

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm getting a weird issue. I have the following set-up:

`Model.xcdatamodeld`

`ModelBackup.xcdatamodeld`

Each of these have their own `NSManagedObjectContext` `NSPersistantStoreCoordinator` and `NSMananagedObjectModel`.

I can read and write to each of these successfully separately. However, if I try to read/write to `Model` at the same time I'm read/writing to `ModelBackup`, I get infinite memory allocation. In the simulator, the CPU will spike to 200% and the memory will increase around 80-100 MB/second. This will eventually crash when memory hits 2.0+GB. This happens when I do a `context save` on both these `NSManagedObjectContext`s. I can read/access them fine.

Anyone know why I'm unable to write to both of these?

I have `Model` with `ConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and `ModelBackup` with `ConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

The idea behind having two different `xcdatamodeld` is a workaround/alternative the `parent-child` core-data pattern. Our app is doing massive updates to the `datamodel` so I want to have a background datamodel perform those updates then when the app launches the next time, switch to the new updated sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can do massive updates with parent/child as long as you pay attention to how much you are writing to disk at any one save.

Second, you can have two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` instances pointed at the same sqlite file and avoid using two files.

Third, What does your code look like for the creation of these contexts? Are you using the second context only within `-performBlock:` calls?

Fourth, what happens when you stop in the middle of that memory allocation?  What does your stack look like?

For your immediate problem, you have an infinite loop.  If I had to guess I would guess that you are using `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`, probably with a `nil` object and each save is kicking off a save to the other context causing a loop.

Seeing the code would help solve your immediate issue.  However I suspect there is an easier solution to your problem.

Comment: Marking as answer as you did (at a glance, doing more thorough testing now) solve the immediate issue - I added in a check for     if (self.managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator != savedContext.persistentStoreCoordinator) inside a notification callback for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. However, I would like to see if I can use the parent/child properly. We're writing approximately 3MB locally to the phone while also deleting another 1MB. I tried using a `-performBlock` on the child but it wouldn't update the parent with all the insertions I did

Comment: The biggest thing to remember with P/C is to keep your reads and writes small. Whenever ANY MOC hits a PSC it will lock the PSC. So you want to keep those locks small.